# Instanceof does not work when I use @EJB, why is that?

Tags: java, instanceof

I got two interface-classes (actually three) in a maven project called "interface":

```
@Local
public interface CrudSessionLocal extends CRUDS {
    
}

public interface ExceptionThrower {
    
    public boolean isThrowException();

    public void setThrowException(boolean throwException);

}
```

I got a bean in a maven project called "server" (that got dependency to "interface"-project) that implements these interfaces:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CrudsTransactionSessionBean implements CrudSessionLocal, ExceptionThrower {
```

I got a servlet in a maven project called "web-client" (that got dependency to "interface"-project, but not to "server"-project). The servlet uses the bean like this code below, remark that the declaration uses the interface.

```
@EJB(beanName = "CrudsTransactionSessionBean")
private CrudSessionLocal crudSessionLocal;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if( crudSessionLocal instanceof ExceptionThrower ) {
        ExceptionThrower exceptionThrower = (ExceptionThrower)crudSessionLocal;
        exceptionThrower.setThrowException(throwException);
    }
```

I thought that use of the interface in the declartion of the bean-member in the servlet is a good practice. For eg I thought that I can reuse the interface.jar and web-client.jar in an other ear but with an other serverlayer like other_server.jar that holds an other bean that does something else as long as the bean is called "CrudsTransactionSessionBean" and implements the interface.

In this case the bean also implements the interface ExceptionThrower. The idea is to check in the servlet if the bean is an instanceof ExceptionThrower, then an exception shall be thrown.

But to my surprise, at runtime, the member-bean is NOT an instance of ExceptionThrower. It is:
"com.myapp.cruds.server.CrudsTransactionSessionBean_d7q6e8_CrudSessionLocalImpl@617fe9e5"
(That sounds like a CrudsTransactionSessionBean to me and that implements ExceptionThrower)

I think I can do it like this, but then I will not acomplish the "loose coupling" between the jar-dependecies.

```
@EJB(beanName = "CrudsTransactionSessionBean")
private CrudsTransactionSessionBean crudSessionLocal;
```

Do you guys see why this is happening?
And to accomplish the "loose coupling" how should I solve it?

Btw I use Java 8 and Weblogic 14

Answer (score 2):

Application servers often inject [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) for session beans to implement EJB features like transaction handling. Such a proxy only implements the session bean interface, but does not expose other details of the session bean implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

After reading the article you linked to, my conclusion is that the proxy do implemet all interfaces.
I added a Junit-test with DebugProxy mentioned in the article
  
 CrudSessionLocal crudSessionLocal = (CrudSessionLocal)DebugProxy.newInstance( new CrudsTransactionSessionBean() );
 ExceptionThrower exceptionThrower = (ExceptionThrower)DebugProxy.newInstance( new CrudsTransactionSessionBean() );
 
 assertNotNull(crudSessionLocal);
 assertNotNull(exceptionThrower);
    
That test unfortenately passes

Comment: That `DebugProxy` uses `interfaces = obj.getClass().getInterfaces()` for [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-). As I said, I assume that application servers only use the session bean interface.

Comment: (By the way, you don't even have to use `assertNotNull` in your test: You'd get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` if the `newInstance` was not assignable to the respective type.)

Comment: You are right, there should have been a exception of course, I did not think of that.

Comment: Btw I listed all interfaces of instance and it does not look what I was hoping for: Class: com.myapp.cruds.server.CrudsTransactionSessionBean_d7q6e8_CrudSessionLocalImpl
-interface: com.myapp.cruds.interfaces.CrudSessionLocal
-interface: weblogic.ejb.container.interfaces.Invokable
-interface: weblogic.ejb.container.interfaces.WLLocalEJBObject

Comment: Hello again @Manfred, I have not done any progress just think of two interesting lines in the link that you provided: 1) "A dynamic proxy class is a class that implements a list of interfaces specified at runtime..." 2) "Since a proxy class implements all of the interfaces specified at its creation..." To me this sound like it should be possible to tell the app server in some way what interfaces it should use when create the Proxy. Unfortunately it looks like the regular programming way is not enough like "public class CrudsTransactionSessionBean implements CrudSessionLocal, ExceptionThrower"

Comment: When _you_ create a Proxy manually _you could_ specify all interfaces (as the `DebugProxy` example does). But you want to use [Enterprise JavaBeans](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/jakarta-enterprise-beans-spec-core-4.0.html), which I believe have another contract. I think that the application server is only required to provide the session bean interface. IMO you should be explicit (at compile time) about the business interface you want/need to use, and avoid `instanceof` checks (at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

It was a really surprise to me that the app-server did not implement all of the interfaces specified in the session bean in the proxy-implementation.
(It was actually a surprise that it was a proxy and not the bean that was injected, and I have bean in the biz for over 20 years. Wow, new lesson each day)

I think I solved it pretty good by using Qualifier.
I found this great tutorial:
http://buraktas.com/create-qualifiers-cdi-beans/

Using that example
I put a Qualifier-annotation class in my interface-project

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ExceptionThrowerQualifier {
}
```

I marked a bean with the qualifier in the server-project:

```
@ExceptionThrowerQualifier
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CrudsTransactionSessionBean implements CrudSessionLocal, ExceptionThrower {
```

In my servlet in the web-client-project I Inject it like this:

```
@Inject
@ExceptionThrowerQualifier
private CrudSessionLocal crudSessionLocal;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if( crudSessionLocal instanceof ExceptionThrower ) {
        ExceptionThrower exceptionThrower = (ExceptionThrower)crudSessionLocal;
        exceptionThrower.setThrowException(throwException);
    }
```

The benifit is that the web-client do not need to be aware of the implementation ("loose coupling" between server and web-client, right?). I could just use the interface classes from the web-client
I do not need to implement the ExceptionThrower in the server. This is nice so I could use "instanceof" if I want to.

But a big drawback is that at least one class need to be annotated with @ExceptionThrowerQualifier. Else it seems like the app server do not know which class to use for injection. (Perhaps this is only true if there are more then one class that implements the interface CrudSessionLocal.)

Ops, looks like I forgot to mention one thing:

```
@Local
public interface ExceptionThrower {
```

To make it work this seems to be needed.

Best regards
Fredrik